# Input data to LSTM network Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, data-science

I have 10 arrays. Each of them represents one data point(input). The shape of the arrays are (16,3), (34,3) etc.. Since LSTM needs 3dim data I reshaped each of those 10 arrays. Example: if it was (16,3) now it is (1,16,3). I tried to get ((1,16,3),(1,34,3),etc..) to be my array shape, in other words 10 arrays in one numpy array with each of shape (1,something,3). When I feed the data with all 10 arrays as one I get the following error:

> Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are
>   passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to
>   see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 10 arrays.

But if I feed one of those arrays with one label it works and overfits(as it should).
If batch_size=1, shouldn't the program take one of those 10 samples to train on?

Here's my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

data = []
directory = 'realData'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    data.append(np.load('realData/' + filename))

for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i].reshape(1,data[i].shape[0],3)

sad = np.array([[0]] * 2)
okay = np.array([[1]] * 3)
happy = np.array([[2]] * 2)
perfect = np.array([[3]] * 3)

labels = np.concatenate([sad,okay,happy,perfect],axis=0)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(None,3)))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')    
model.fit(data, labels,
          batch_size=1,
          epochs=15,
          validation_data=(data, labels))

score, acc = model.evaluate(data, labels, batch_size=1)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTM input while training expects a Numpy array. In this case you can pad the each array to the highest length in the batch/input and then convert them to Numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

def pad_txt_data(arr):
  paded_arr = []
  prefered_len = len(max(arr, key=len))

  for each_arr in arr:
    if len(each_arr) < prefered_len:
      print('padding array with zero')
      while len(each_arr) < prefered_len:
          each_arr.insert(0, np.zeros(3))
      paded_arr.append(each_arr)
  return np.array(paded_arr)

# your_arr = [shape(16, 3), shape(32, 3), . .. .]
# loop through your_arr and prepare a single array with all the arrays and pass this array to padding function.

interm_arr = []
def input_prep():
  for each_arr in your_arr:
    interm_arr.append(each_arr)
  final_arr = pad_txt_data(interm_arr)
```

So the final array will have the shape of (input_size, maxlength, features_size). In this case if you have 10 arrays in input final_arr will have a shape (10, max_lenth, 3). You can use this as an input to LSTM.

Comment: each_arr.insert(0, np.zeros(3))
insert command does not exist.. its not working the way you thought it will. It gave me a wierd shape, I'll try and adjust the function myself

Comment: I adjusted the function to work, it produces the expected output but provides the same error

Comment: if each_arr is not an numpy array it throughs that error "insert command does not exist". and what was the adjustment that you made? can you paste the updated code?

Comment: I added each_arr = np.concatenate([each_arr, [[0,0,0]]], axis=0) instead of each_arr.insert(0, np.zeros(3)).

Comment: try this and look at the shape of each_arr and final input once. b= np.zeros(3) each_arr = np.concatenate([each_arr, b], axis=0)

Comment: Dimensions are not the same shape like that

Comment: can you print the shapes of your 10 arrays here before padding.

Comment: (89, 3)
(16, 3)
(34, 3)
(18, 3)
(19, 3)
(9, 3)
(23, 3)
(11, 3)
(18, 3)
(19, 3)

AND

I have also tried (1,something,3), but when i do this and data=np.array(data) it gives broadcasting error. Cant broadcast array of shape (something,3) to (1)

Comment: Also if data = np.array(data).reshape(10,1,1) gives ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: okay your first comment solved the problem. You only had one issue: paded_arr.append(each_arr) needs to be one TAB back

Answer (score 0):

Your model expects as input a numpy array where the first dimension is the batch dimension. Instead, you are providing it a list of numpy arrays. You can convert the list of arrays into a single array with `data = np.array(data)`.

Comment: That causes the following error:
    data = np.array(data)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (89,3) into shape (1)